# in numpy covariance, ValueError: array is too big

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I try to find eigen value and vector using numpy,

I get error on covariance function, the data_mat contain data with 39906 columns
and 200 rows.
as you can see it said,the array is too big,
can anyone tell me how to make the cov works with large variables ?

```
import numpy as nm
....
eigeVal, raw_eigeVec = nm.linalg.eig(nm.cov(nm.matrix(data_mat,dtype=object)))




 File "pca.py", line 61, in find_eagen
    eigeVal, raw_eigeVec = nm.linalg.eig(nm.cov(nm.matrix(data_mat,dtype=object)))
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 1766, in cov
     return (dot(X, X.T.conj()) / fact).squeeze()
 **ValueError: array is too big.**
```

Comment: How much memory do you have? You're trying to create a 39906 x 39906 matrix - that's 1592488836 elements. Assuming your arrays are float64, that would require about 12GB of memory.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want the covariance matrix of `X.T`, which would be a 200 x 200 array? What do the rows and columns of `X` correspond to?

Comment: You are doing Principal Component Analysis (PCA), and if your data is sparse, you might be able to use methods in `sklearn` that provide variants of PCA that can handle sparse matrices. For example : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.RandomizedPCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.RandomizedPCA

Comment: @ali_m I only have 4GB of memory, the X.T occurs in numpy library calculation of cov. so I don't know what X is.

Comment: Is `data_mat.shape` really `(200, 39906)`? Based on the few lines of code you've posted, I would expect to see that error if its shape was `(39906, 200)`. You should probably set a breakpoint using `pdb` and check.

Comment: @ali_m yes, I have checked the shape, and it's (200,39906)

Comment: Are you able to just call `np.dot(data_mat, data_mat.T.conj())`?

Comment: @ali_m when I try to call np.dot(data_mat, data_mat.T.conj()) it gives me ValueError: array is too big. the dot function can't handle (39906x39906). do I have any solution ? :D

Comment: aha! what is the `dtype` of `data_mat`?

Comment: dtype of data_mat is numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix, and dtype of each element in the matrix is float32. I do scan the csv using memmap.

Comment: `numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix` is the class, i.e. `type(data_map)`. I want to know what its `dtype` attribute is, i.e. `data_mat.dtype`. is it really `float32`, or is it something else?

Comment: @ali_m yes, it's numpy float32

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54800/discussion-between-ali-m-and-aldy-syahdeini).